# Sort and iterate over the first letters of a large list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, grouping

I have an ***input*** list of strings that are split by a comma like so:

```
list_to_split = ['flyer, black and white', 'flyer, blue', 'fly-swatter, black', 'helmet, heavy',
'armlet, silver and gold', 'cherry, black', 'violin, very old', 'concrete, grey']
```

I'd like to iterate over items starting with the same letters and update an empty dictionary with them to get an ***desired output*** that looks like this:

```
letter_ordered_dict = {'a': ['armet'], 'c': ['cherry', 'concrete'], 'f': ['flyer', 'fly-swatter'],
'h': ['helmet'], 'v': ['violin']}
```

The way I am attempting this, to begin, is by obviously first grabbing the first elements of the original list with a comprehension:

```
list_split_by_first_element = [first_elm.split(',')[0] for elm in list_that_has_been_ordered]
list_split_by_first_element.sort()
```

This produces the output:

```
['armlet', 'cherry', 'concrete', 'flyer', 'flyer', 'fly-swatter', 'helmet', 'violin']
```

The part I am stuck on is how to group by these elements on their first letters and skip duplicates to generate the output above.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: I think you're better off not trying to be so "elegant", and just looping through the original list a single time, adding members to your dictionary item by item as you go.

Comment: Yeah probably the best. Internally within the loop I could split the string element further by the first element of the string itself, link that to the dictionary key, and internally append to the list of values.

Comment: Do you need the items to be sorted within each letter entry? Or will any order be OK? If the items within each letter list can be out of order, then there are relatively simple/fast methods for duplicate removal using the `set()` type. If they should be sorted, that makes it a little trickier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this kind of scanning/aggregation problem, you generally need a loop rather than a list comprehension. Assuming `list_split_by_first_element` is sorted, this should work:

```
letter_ordered_dict = dict()
prev_word = ''
for word in list_split_by_first_element:
    if word == prev_word:
        # skip repeated words
        continue
    letter = word[0]
    letter_ordered_dict.setdefault(letter, []).append(word)
```

Note that `dict.setdefault` either looks up the key or sets it to the specified value if it doesn't exist, which is exactly what you want here.

With a very long list or a lot of duplicate words, you may find it faster to sort the sublists rather than the full list. Then something like this could work:

```
list_to_split = ['flyer, black and white', 'flyer, blue', 'fly-swatter, black', 'helmet, heavy',
'armlet, silver and gold', 'cherry, black', 'violin, very old', 'concrete, grey']

set_dict = dict()
for phrase in list_to_split:
    word, rest = phrase.split(',', 1)
    set_dict.setdefault(word[0], set()).add(word)
letter_ordered_dict = {
    letter: sorted(words)
    for letter, words in set_dict.items()
}
```

If the sublists for each letter don't need to be sorted internally, you could save some time by replacing `sorted` with `list` in the second example.

Comment: I love this solution because I'm always a fan of a bit longer, but more obvious inputs and outputs. I also added certain edge cases where there are no commas to split. Thank you for this!

Answer (score 2):

This should do the job:

```py
import itertools
tmp = sorted(e.split(',')[0] for e in list_to_split) # list_split_by_first_element
letter_ordered_dict = {k:list(set(v)) for k,v in itertools.groupby(tmp, lambda item: item[0])}
```

**Output result in `letter_ordered_dict`:**

```py
{'a': ['armlet'],
 'c': ['concrete', 'cherry'],
 'f': ['fly-swatter', 'flyer'],
 'h': ['helmet'],
 'v': ['violin']}
```

Comment: I love the power of Python one-liners!  (the `tmp` variable is only a readability refactorization)  Nicely done.

Answer (score 0):

So I've written a code from the point after getting the list_of_words

```
list_of_words = ['armlet', 'cherry', 'concrete', 'flyer', 'flyer', 'fly-swatter', 'helmet', 'violin']

list_of_words = list(set(list_of_words))

first_char_dict = dict()

for word in list_of_words:
    if word[0] in first_char_dict:
        first_char_dict[word[0]].append(word)
    else:
        first_char_dict[word[0]] = [word]
        
print(first_char_dict)
```

output : `{'h': ['helmet'], 'v': ['violin'], 'f': ['fly-swatter', 'flyer'], 'c': ['cherry', 'concrete'], 'a': ['armlet']}`

Though I would like to bring you notice to the point that you are selecting only one world while splitting the string. Is that what you need ?